# Sprite Kit didBeginContact Being Called Twice

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skphysicsbody

I have a game where a sprite is coming into contact with a wall, and when on contact I remove the sprite and do game condition things like increase the players score etc. However, for some odd reason,  didBeginContact is called every time the sprite comes into contact with the wall, even though I remove the node every time! Why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact*)contact
{
   NSLog(@"Did Begin Contact");

// First body is always animal
SKPhysicsBody *firstBody;
SKPhysicsBody *secondBody;

if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyA;
    secondBody = contact.bodyB;
}
else
{
    firstBody = contact.bodyB;
    secondBody = contact.bodyA;
}

// Animal Clean Up (Removal) after contact with wall
[firstBody.node removeFromParent];

score++;

}
```

Comment: Your question is worded in a confusing manner.  Your code will remove the animal every time there beginContact is called.  This is expected.  If the animal is removed, there will be no additional beginContacts called unless you create more animals that hit the wall.

Comment: Also, if the wall is actually multiple wall segments or a body with multiple shapes (not sure if this is possible in SK/iOS 8) you may receive multiple contact events.

Comment: @meisenman I've tested it and only created a single animal and didBeginContact was still called twice. However, I do a check now that if firstBody.node = nil then I return; before increasing the score. This seems to be working well but I wish I did not have to use a workaround like this

Comment: You actually should be validating that the firstBody has a categoryBitMask of AnimalCategory and the secondBody has a categoryBitMask of Wall.  Right now, any contact event will try to remove first body and add to score.